# Puppeteer is generating a .pdf with nearly 1000 blank pages when I am using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer in TypeScript to generate a PDF for data collection and wanted to display a chart with Chart.js. The chart is getting displayed, but when it does, the pdf contains hundreds of blank pages. I generate the pdf through a template with handlebars and the preview in the browser is fine. I am using a flex-container with these properties in css:

```
.flex-container {
  display : flex;
  justify-content: space-between
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
  alighn-items: stretch;
}
```

The pdf currently looks like: (censored due to sensible data)
[PDF-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGYRu.png)

The code for the generation looks like:

```
private convertation(data: any, currentRepo: string) {
    //Start convertatio
    this.getTemplateHtml()
        .then(async (res) => {object handlebars");
            const template = hb.compile(res, { strict: true });

            const result = template(data);
            const html = result;
            fs.writeFileSync("./res/index.html", html);
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ["--no-sandbox"] });

            const outfile = "./output/testdata/" + currentRepo.split('/')[0] + "-" + currentRepo.split('/')[1] + ".pdf";
            if (fs.existsSync(outfile)) {
                fs.unlinkSync(outfile);
            }

            // console.log("New page ...");
            const page = await browser.newPage();

            var contentHtml = fs.readFileSync("./res/index.html", 'utf8');
            
            const t_width = 1366;
            const t_height = Math.floor(t_width / 16 * 9);
            await page.setViewport({width: t_width, height: t_height, deviceScaleFactor: 1});
            await sleep(10); 
            await page.goto('http://localhost:7000/index.html', { timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
            // Wait for the data to be rendered in the final state;
            await sleep(100);  // analog to deprecated "page.waitForTimeout(200)"
            const height = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.offsetHeight);
            const width = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.offsetWidth);
            console.log("width: ", width, " height: ", height);
            same folder as this file.
            const dpi = 100; // 96 or 72 or 100 => with 100 it works, whyever
            await page.pdf({
                path: outfile,
                scale: 1,
                width: (t_width / dpi) + "in",
                height: (t_height / dpi) + "in",
                // landscape: false,
                displayHeaderFooter: false,

            });
            await browser.close();
            console.log("PDF Generated");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
```

I tried

```
@media print {        
  .chartjs-size-monitor{
            position:fixed !important;       
}   
 }
```

But it did not worked well.
I already tried to take a screenshot of the chart with Google Charts and insert it (this worked), but we need to do it with the rendered Chart due to the font.

Comment: Why not? The data is censored.

Comment: Okay, didn't knew that. I changed it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until the content of the page is loaded before running `pdf`.
I recommend the `domcontentloaded` option.

```js
const HTML = `${HTML_CONTENT}`
await page.setContent(HTML,
        {
          waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
        },
      )
```

For more options check de docs.
https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.setcontent

Comment: The result is the same. It looks like:
var contentHtml = fs.readFileSync("http://localhost:7000/index.html", 'utf8');
                
                 await page.setContent(contentHtml, 
                    {
                     waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"
                    }
                 );